# Can not connect to my webserver on my own IP

Tags: centos, vps, cpanel

Lately I'm having trouble connecting to my VPS Webserver.

Every morning when I try to connect to my webserver via pop ,visit a website that runs on the server or even ping the server, I get no response.

When I connect to the server console via my hosting company's website and let the server reboot everything is fine again.. until the morning after, then I have to reboot it again or else I can't get any connection to it.

This problem is only on my own IP address, not when I try to connect/ping the server from any other IP address (e.g. my neighbours house)

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this?

Server info:

- CENTOS 6.6 x86_64 kvm
- Cpanel WHM 11.50.0 (build 23)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying the FQDN or the IP of your server?

You can do a few things to troubleshoot this:

- Check that you haven't put your webserver in `/etc/hosts` with the wrong IP
- Try to connect through the same IP but from a different device e.g. a smartphone connected via your Wi-Fi; if it doesn't work either, the problem is your ISP so you should contact them about the issue

Comment: I tried both, FQDN and IP , on both ways I can't make any connection from any device when on my home network.
Only after I reboot the VPS via the console on the website of the hosting company, I can do everything again. 
So it appears to me its something in the server not my ISP..?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to check your firewall on your server. It seems you get automaticaly banned somehow.

Comment: I checked IPTables and my IP address doesnt appear anywhere in it?

Comment: When you checked iptables, could you connect/ping to your server? If yes, you should check it when the problem occurs via server console.